# Sort ranges on /questions/unanswered is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, unanswered

The following API request should return all unanswered questions with a score of at least 30:

> http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/questions/unanswered?sort=votes&min=30

However, the response consists of 250 items and hardly any of them have a score of more than 30. In fact, only two of them do. This is verified by removing the `/unanswered` qualifier and running the following request:

> http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/questions?sort=votes&min=30

This route does indeed return the correct number of items (currently 26) and each of them has a score >= 30 as expected. Obviosuly if there are only 26 *total* questions that have a score >= 30 then there cannot possibly be more unanswered questions than that.

Comment: I should also point out that `/no-answers` works correctly. This appears limited to `/unanswered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

There was a bogus bit of SQL there applying a creation sort instead of a vote one.